# Need help with implementing Railscast 198 in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, railscasts

I have been trying to implement Ryan Bates Railscast 198 into rails 3 for like 4 days... at least at night if you know what I mean.  Anyway, here is the code I have right now:

User controller actions (Devise setup to show the different states of approved):

```
def index
  if params[:approved] == "false"
    @users = User.find_all_by_approved(false)
  elsif
    @users = User.find_all_by_approved(true)
  else
    @users = User.all
  end
end

def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      format.html { redirect_to root_path flash[:notice] = "User was successfully updated." }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "edit" }
    end
  end
end

def edit_individual
  @users = User.find(params[:user_ids])
end

def update_individual
  @users = User.update(params[:users].keys, params[:users].values).reject { |p| p.errors.empty? }
    if @users.empty?
      flash[:notice] = "Users updated"
      redirect_to users_url
    else
      render :action => "edit_individual"
    end
  end 
end
```

My User#index

```
<h1> Users</h1>

 <%= link_to "All Users", :action => "index" %> |
 <%= link_to "Users awaiting approval", :action => "index", :approved => "false"%>
 |
 <%= link_to "Approved Users", :action => "index", :approved => "true" %>

 <%= form_tag edit_individual_users_path, :method => :put do  %>
 <table>
   <tr>
    <th>Email Address</th>
    <th>Approved</th>
    <th></th>
   </tr>

<% for user in @users %>
 <tr>
   <td> <%= user.email %></td>
   <td><%= check_box_tag user.id %></td>
   <td> <%= link_to "Edit", edit_user_path(user) %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>

<p><%= submit_tag "Edit Checked" %></p>
  </table>

<% end %>
```

And the User#edit_individual

```
<%= form_tag update_individual_users_path, :method => :put do %>
<% for user in @users %>
<%= fields_for "users[]", user do |f| %>
  <h2><%=h user.name %></h2>
  <p><%= check_box_tag user.id %></p>
<% end %>
<% end %>
<p><%= submit_tag "Submit" %></p>
```

<% end %>

routes.rb

```
devise_for :users
  resources :users do
    collection do 
      post :edit_individual
      put :update_individual
    end
  end 
end
```

So I handled the basic by googling: `fields_for` needs an "=" stuff like that.  #index shows fine but if I check a checkbox and then hit the edit checked button I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#update

Couldn't find User with id=edit_individual
```

Any ideas??? thanks so much

Comment: I'm a bit lost in your `index` method's conditional statement; I'm almost positive it's not doing what you think it is. Take a look at how the HTML is actually being rendered, particularly the form field names, and make sure it matches up with your expectations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your routes.rb and controller code, as it's quite a bit off from the code on Railscast 198's page:  http://railscasts.com/episodes/198-edit-multiple-individually

It's best to just copy it in if you're new to rails and adjust for using users instead of products.  Then go through it to try to understand what it does.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. notes.  I'll go back through and make it all work for the railscast then reimplement the index action and other items.